# How to deploy Angular Universal app to Node.js production server?

Tags: node.js, angular, pm2, angular-universal

I have an Angular 8 application with Universal that I want to deploy to a shared web host production server. I checked with the web host in advance and they told me that hosting an angular universal web app is possible on their shared web hosting. However, whatever I do, I can't get the website to work. When I go to the website I keep seeing the message: "This site can't be reached"

Things I have done so far:

1. Build project with npm run build:ssr which created a dist folder with a browser and server folder and a server.js file
2. Move the dist folder to the server inside the public_html folder.
   Then accessed the server through SSH and did these:
3. install Node.js and npm
4. npm install
5. npm install pm2 -g
6. pm2 start dist/server.js

pm2 starts without problems.

These are some of the project files. If any are missing please ask and I'll add them to the question.

Part of the package.json with the scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run ProjectName:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  },
```

server.js from the build (only the express part, since it's 25000+ lines):

```
const app = express__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = Object(path__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["join"])(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap } = __webpack_require__(144);
// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);
// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["static"](DIST_FOLDER, {
    maxAge: '1y'
}));
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { req });
});
// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

According to several answers on SO or elsewhere you "simply" copy paste the dist folder to the server, run pm2 and your website supposedly works. I feel like there's a lot missing to get it working though.

Does someone know how to properly deploy an Angular Universal website to a production server?

Comment: Does your shared hosting have a web server that you can configure, e.g. Apache or nginx?

Comment: I can see Apache is running when I go directly to http:// ip-adres

Comment: Can you create a vhost in apache? Technically you need to redirect traffic to your nodejs server from Apache config

Comment: Not sure how to do that. I'll try to figure that out. Do I need to do that in some config file?

Comment: It depends on your hosting company. Sometimes you have to do it with`.htaccess` files

Comment: There actually is already a .htaccess file present on the server. So I just put configuration in there and it should work? Do you know how to?

Comment: Have a look here: https://blog.daudr.me/painless-angular-ssr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a tool in my DirectAdmin console called 'NodeJS Selector', because PM2 kept causing problems for me. It's a tool to install your application, do npm install and start the app. So basically what you'd do using SSH, but in a fancy UI. The setup looks like this:
[image: NodeJS Selector setup]

With my folder structure looking like this:

```
domains
    - appname.com
        - public_html
            - browser (=> this set as the document root in Apache, because index is located here)
                - index.html
                - .htaccess
                - other files...
            - server
            - server.js
            - package.json
```

I had my web host do 2 things, because I'm not a root user on the server. They set the **documentroot** to the browser folder in Apache's httpd.conf file. In the same file they also added **proxy** settings to port 4000 because that's where my app is running on. So in the httpd.conf file will be something like this:

```
 DocumentRoot "/domains/appname.com/public_html/browser"

 <Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPass / https://localhost:4000/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:4000/
```

Next in the NodeJS selector you set the root to where the startup file is located (in my case server.js). The package.json needs to be in de public_html folder as well so you can do **npm install** in the Selector.

To start the app you click **'Run JS script'** and choose the serve:ssr option and it runs the node server command.

The Angular docs describe how you have to rewrite some rules on the server. Apache is installed on my web server so I added an .htaccess file with the rewrite rules from the docs. However this app is served by Node and Node can serve the actual paths. So in my case I didn't have to add the .htaccess file with rewrite rules. On the contrary, when I added the .htaccess file it caused the Universal side of my app not to fully render. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570296/angular-universal-only-showing-page-source-for-first-page) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In `server.ts` file change

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
```

to

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'browser');
```

Now build the application by `npm run build:ssr` and copy everything inside of `dist` folder to your public folder (on host). Remember, instead of `pm2 start dist/server.js`, you should run `pm2 start server.js`.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately no luck. What is this change doing exactly? If I look at the -out.log file of pm2 it says: "Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000" Do I also need to configure the host and port somewhere to redirect to my domain or ip?

Comment: 'This site can't be reached' error means that you are serving the website on wrong destination. So, one of the possibilities was removing the dist folder (which solved this problem for me, personally). I suggest you to ask web host whether the port is open or not, and how you can proxy this port to 80 (for http) and 443 (for https).