# Angular Universal only showing page source for first page

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal web app running on a shared web server. I ran it with a tool that is in my DirectAdmin called NodeJS Selector. With this I could npm install and server:ssr the server.js file. It's working, I can browse to all my pages and I see all the content.

**The problem** however is in the page source. When I go the base url (www.example.com/) and I right-click => 'view page source', I can see the content of the home page just like Universal is supposed to do. But when I go to any of my other pages I don't see the content in the page source, only the app-root tag.

I feel like this has something to do with either the router module, something in my server.ts or perhaps even a configuration in Apache, which the server is running on, but I can't figure out what it is.

**I also tried** running my app with pm2, but that didn't load universal at all. With pm2 I only saw the app-root tag in the page source. Also the pm2 instance I had running disappeared every day, even when doing 'pm2 save' on the running instance. When I entered SSH the next day and did 'pm2 list' there was nothing there... So that's why I switched to the **NodeJS Selector tool** which got it working halfway now.

This is my app-routing.module.ts (left some paths and imports out for brevity):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'generators', component: GeneratorComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  { path: 'disclaimer', component: DisclaimerComponent},
  { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled', scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

server.ts:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Does anyone know why only the homepage is showing content in the page source of the browser and all other pages only the app-root tag?

**Update**

Here is my .htaccess file, if it helps:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I had my web host edit Apache's httpd.conf file with a proxy setting to port 4000 and set the document root to where my index file is located:

```
 DocumentRoot "/domains/appname.com/public_html/browser"

 <Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPass / https://localhost:4000/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:4000/
```

Should I add more configuration to Apache for the other pages to be server-side rendered?

Comment: So if you do a hard browser refresh on an internal page, you don’t see rendered content on a view source?

Comment: Just tried that and still not seeing content in the source. I also tried calling the page with curl and I'm not getting content there either. Only the app-root tag.

Comment: is this on an external server? Or localhost? If on localhost, you’re going to port 4000 right?

Comment: It's already on an external production server. It's running on port 4000. I had my web host edit the virual host in Apache as I can't reach those files myself, to proxy to port 4000. Locally everything was running fine though. Only on production it's showing this behavior.

Comment: I wonder if the rewrite is actually needed in this case..

Comment: The rewrite in .htaccess is necessary to prevent 404 errors when refreshing the page in Angular. I'll try modifying some of the settings in that file after work, but the redirect to ./index.html is a minimum.

Comment: With a normally build app - agreed. However, node should be serving this right? And the node server can serve the actual paths.. I would also explain why only your index has rendered content..

Comment: @MikeOne So I removed the .htaccess file and that was it! Routes are still working and I'm not getting any 404 errors on refresh like you suspected. If you'd like to add your solution as an answer I can accept it and upvote the hell out of it! Took me a while to get my site fully functional. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that was the issue! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Angular Universal to render on the server-side, you need to remove the .htaccess rewrite rule to index.html. The node server will handle the requests of all incoming routes now so rewriting should no longer be done.